# Calculating age in Delphi

Tags: delphi

```
iAge := 2013 - StrToInt(sJ) ;
if iAge< 18
then
begin
bDatum := False ;
ShowMessage('You must be older than 18!') ;
Exit ;
end; //IF
```

If you use this it will just take the current year and the year the user typed in and test if he is 18 or not, I'm looking for a way to to calculate the age of the user using the month and day as well but it was to no avail, so I was hoping to get some help from Stackoverflow.

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to think about this is that if you know the date when the person was born, you simply need to work out whether or not their 18th birthday has passed.

1. Ask the user for their date of birth. Get that in the form of day, month and year.
2. Add 18 to the year.
3. Convert that into a date with [`EncodeDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.EncodeDate).
4. Compare that to today's date, which can be found by calling [`Date`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Date).

The code would look like this:

```
if EncodeDate(dobYear + 18, dobMonth, dobDay) > Date then
  ShowMessage('Too young');
```

Now, this almost works, but it will fail if the person was born on a leap day, that is the 29<sup>th</sup> February. You'd need to add a special case to handle that. For example, a crude approach would be like this:

```
if (dobMonth=2) and (dobDay=29) then
  dobDay := 28;
if EncodeDate(dobYear + 18, dobMonth, dobDay) > Date then
  ShowMessage('Too young');
```

---

Looks like I've just re-invented the wheel here. Always a bad idea. You can call `IncYear` from `DateUtils` to get this done, and not have to worry about leap days.

```
if IncYear(EncodeDate(dobYear, dobMonth, dobDay), 18) > Date then
  ShowMessage('Too young');
```

Comment: I know Stackoverflow doesn't want you to use the comment section to "+1" and "Thanks" but I just want to say thanks a lot for the quick reply and the effort you put into the answer, saved me a lot of time and headaches :)

Comment: @David, are you sure about the "leap day" thing? Shouldn't `EncodeDate` take care of this situation?

Comment: @kobik It throws an exception. And rightly so. You cannot expect it to encode a date that does not exist.

Comment: I see what you mean now. in that case I would some sort of DateAdd(18 years) ?

Comment: @kobik Adding 18 years is harder than you might think. What is a year? How many days? 365 or 366?

Comment: OK, There is an `IncYear` in `DateUtils` which should take care of leap years (it is based on `IncMonth` from `SysUtils`). not tested though...

Comment: If you encode it, then add 18 years, you won't get an exception with leap days: `IncYear(EncodeDate(dobYear, dobMonth, dobDay), 18)`.

Comment: Thank you Marcus and kobik.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi stores the date as a real number - you must use the Extended type

```
function Age(TheDate: TDate): integer;

var

  I: Extended;                                   // Extended is a special type of real variable

begin

  I := Now() - TheDate;                     // Now() is todays date in TDate format

                                                          //  The type conflict is apparently ignored



  Result := round(I/365.25);

  If Result > 110 then Result := 0;    // this copes with a missing date string



end; // Start date in Delphi is 30/12/1899

{============================================================}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simpler:

```
isUnder18 := YearsBetween(DOB, Now()) < 18;
```

[YearsBetween](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.DateUtils.YearsBetween)